Differentiating Warranted Growth and Natural Growth in Harrod's model
Reading up on the Harrod Model, I found the definitions of the various terms as such

Warrented Growth: full capacity growth rate of income in an economy


Natural Growth: maximum growth rate that an economy can achieve with its available natural resources

I find it difficult to differentiate warranted growth and natural growth. From just understanding the meaning, my guess is that warranted growth is the (desired) potential growth and natural growth is the theoretical maximum growth at productive capacity. However, I fail to understand the economic intuition behind this. What confuses me more is if natural growth is the maximum growth rate, how is it possible that warrented growth exceeds natural growth (as one of the cases analysed in the harrod model)
How would you explain the differences between these two terms simply.
Just a side question, does steady state growth mean sustained growth/ tenable growth?
